# Show that there are infinitely many positive integers $n$ such that $p$ divides $2^{n}-n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation, solution-verification

> Let $p$ be a prime. Show that there are infinitely many positive integers $n$ such that $p$ divides $2^{n}-n$

**Proof**:

If $p=2, p$ divides $2^{n}-n$ for every even positive integer $n$.

We assume that $p$ is odd. By Fermat's little theorem, $2^{p-1} \equiv 1(\bmod p)$.

It follows that
$
2^{(p-1)^{2 k}} \equiv 1 \equiv(p-1)^{2 k} \quad(\bmod p)
$
that is, $p$ divides $2^{n}-n$ for $n=(p-1)^{2 k}$

***now i want to clarify two things***

**1) How by FLT they concluded that**

$
2^{(p-1)^{2 k}} \equiv 1 \quad(\bmod p)
$

i mean by taking both sides $2k$ power we should get 
$
2^{(p-1){2 k}} \equiv 1 \quad(\bmod p)
$
???

**2)My proof** -

instead of taking both sides $2k$ power as the author did i take both sides $k$ power and obtained

$
2^{(p-1){k}} \equiv 1 \quad(\bmod p)
$

now i put $
{(p-1){k}} \equiv 1 \quad(\bmod p)
$

which implies {$k=p-1,2p-1,3p-1,........$}

so hence our infinite set is $n=${$(p-1)(p-1),(p-1)(2p-1),(p-1)(3p-1).........$}

**Is this correct???**

thankyou

Comment: The author raised the left hand side to the power $(p-1)^{2k-1}$, I think. In either case, $1$ stays equal to $1$.

Comment: Since $2^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p$ we have $2^{(p-1)m}\equiv 1 \pmod p$ for all integers $m$, so just take $m=(p-1)^{2k-1}$.

Comment: @lulu thanks ,a little mistake ,m cannot be integer it has to be positive intger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As lulu said in the comments,
$$\forall m,\quad 2^{(p-1)m}\equiv 1\pmod p.$$
The author then took $m=(p-1)^{2k-1}$.

But your proof is indeed correct, and a bit more general: it suffices to take $m$ such that $(p-1)m\equiv-m\equiv 1\pmod p$, and this is precisely your infinite set.

Comment: ahh,i missed it ,thanks..

Answer (score 2):

There's probably a theorem that  makes quick work of the problem, but an easy way to see things is to look at the exponent $(p-1)^{2k}$ and rewrite it as $(p-1)^{2k-1}(p-1)$. Call this exponent $m(p-1)$. Now $2^{(p-1)^{2k}}=2^{m(p-1)}=(2^m)^{p-1}\equiv 1 \bmod p$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as you say $n=(kp-1)(p-1)$, then
$$
\begin{align}
2^n-n
&=\overbrace{2^{(kp-1)(p-1)}}^{2^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod{p}}-\overbrace{\vphantom{2^1}(kp-1)(p-1)}^{\equiv1\pmod{p}}\\
&\equiv0\pmod{p}
\end{align}
$$